# Find sec $\theta$ In the rectangular prism shown,

Tags: geometry

Find sec $\theta$ In the rectangular prism (Answer:$\frac{13\sqrt2}{11}$)

[image]

I try but I can´t finish.

$\triangle GFJ: FJ^2=3^2+1^2 = 10$

$\triangle FJC:CJ^2=FJ^2+CF^2=10+4^2=26$

$\triangle JAH: AJ^2=4^2+1^2 = 17$

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using vectors? Scalar Product?

Comment: Or use the Cosine Rule in $\triangle CJA$ since you already have the lengths of the sides

Comment: Your last pythagoras was in triangle JAH, not JAC. I agree with David, that since you now have all three side lengths of JAC (which is not a right angled triangle), you can apply the cosine rule to get $\cos \theta = 1/\sec \theta$.

Comment: @DavidQuinn It is not allowed to use vectors

Comment: @JaapScherphuis  Thanks for the alert..Fixed

Comment: Law of cosines is not allowed?

Comment: @BobDobbs LAw of cossines is allowed...I managed to solve it..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$AC^2=13$

Law of cosines: $AJ^2=AC^2+CJ^2 - 2(AC)(CJ)\cos \theta$

$17=13 + 26 - 2\sqrt{13}\sqrt{26} \cos \theta$

$-22 = -26\sqrt{2} \cos \theta$

$\sec \theta=13 \sqrt{2}/11$

Answer (score 0):

$△GFJ:FJ^2=3^2+1^2=10\\
△FJC:CJ^2=FJ^2+CF^2=10+42=26\\
△JAH:AJ^2=4^2+1^2=17\\
AC^2= 2^2+3^2=13\\
\triangle ACJ:T.Cossenos:\\
AJ^2=CJ^2+AC^2-2CJ.AC.cos\theta \implies 17=26+13-2.\sqrt{26}\sqrt{13}cos\theta\\
cos\theta = \frac{22}{2.13\sqrt2}=\frac{11}{13\sqrt{2}}\\
\therefore \boxed{sec\theta = \frac{13\sqrt2}{11}}$